# Stanford NER is not properly extracting percentages

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to extract percentages using Stanford NER. But it is not extracting percentage properly.

```
inp_str = 'total revenue received was one hundred and twenty five percent 125% for last financial year'
split_inp_str = inp_str.split()
st = StanfordNERTagger('english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz')
print(st.tag(split_inp_str))
```

This gives following output

```
[('total', 'O'), ('revenue', 'O'), ('received', 'O'), ('was', 'O'), ('one', 'O'), ('hundred', 'O'), ('and', 'O'), ('twenty', 'O'), ('five', 'PERCENT'), ('percent', 'PERCENT'), ('125%', 'O'), ('for', 'O'), ('last', 'O'), ('financial', 'O'), ('year', 'O')]
```

Why is it not extracting **125%** or **one hundred and twenty five percent**?

Comment: I get PERCENT for "one hundred and twenty five percent 125%" when I use Stanford CoreNLP 3.7.0.  I'm running the Java code.  If you use NLTK I am not entirely sure what is being run.

Answer (score -1):

You need to tokenize the sentence rather than split(). Try the following code.

```
from nltk import word_tokenize

inp_str = 'total revenue received was one hundred and twenty five percent 125% for last financial year'
split_inp_str = word_tokenize(inp_str)
st = StanfordNERTagger('english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz')
print(st.tag(split_inp_str))
```